# How to tune MySQL connection pool params in context.xml

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, connection-pooling, context.xml

In Tomcat, your `META-INF/context.xml` file can contain a JNDI datasource object like so:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/dbLogging"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.server.example.com:3306/my_db"
    username="my_user"
    password="my_password"

    maxActive="15"
    maxIdle="3"
    maxWait="-1"
/>
```

What calculations/algorithms/heuristics/etc. can I use to tune what the values of the connection pool settings (`maxActive`, `maxIdle`, `maxWait`, etc.) should be?

Are there any other major connection pool settings I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Just read the documentation and tune your datasource accordingly: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use

```
<Context>
   ...
   <Resource name="jdbc/oralocal" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         url="your URL"
         driverClassName="driver class name"
         username="dbuser" password="password"
         maxActive="20" 
         maxIdle="3" 
         maxWait="10000"
         poolPreparedStatements="true"
         maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
         validationQuery="SQL Query" />
</Context>
```

Pooling of prepared statements and maximum open prepared statements also you can use to tune prepared statements.

[have a Look at this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abehs/index.html)